# Detecting expunged messages with IMAP

Tags: imap

So IMAP has a feature where, once I've looked at a mailbox, I can efficiently look for any new messages by asking it for any new UIDs which I haven't seen yet.

But I how do I efficiently find *expunged* messages? I haven't found any commands for doing this yet; my only option is to retrieve the full UID list of the mailbox and looking for missing ones. This is rather suboptimal.

I have mailboxes with 25000+ messages. Scanning one of these mailboxes takes megabytes of traffic just to do the UID SEARCH command, so I'd like to avoid this. Is there anything hidden in the depths of the IMAP protocol that I'm missing?

Comment: No, you're not, but the seldom supported QRESYNC extension is designed to help with this problem.

Comment: If you're syncing the entire mailbox, you can be somewhat clever in matching sequenc numbers to UIDs to try to find smaller ranges of deleted messages, if you expect few messages to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, for offline use this can work:

Since big mailboxes typically grow big by having many messages added and few deleted, you can optimise for there being large unchanged parts of the messages. If your clientside store contains 10000 messages, then you can send 'x UID SEARCH 2000,4000,6000,8000,10000` which will return five UIDs in one SEARCH response. Depending on which ones have changed, you know whether there have been any expunges in each fifth of the mailbox, so if the mailbox hasn't changed you've verified that very cheaply. If a particular fifth has changed, you can retrieve all 2000 UIDs in that.

QRESYNC/CONDSTORE is much nicer though, and also let you resync flag state.

Answer (score 2):

The only effective answer I know to this is to change the problem.

Instead of learning which of the 25000 messages have been deleted, the client can learn which of the messages *in its cache* have been deleted and which ones still exist, and that can be done fairly efficiently. One approach is to keep a per-message flag in the client, "this message has been observed to exist in this IMAP connection" and when you access a cached message for which the flag isn't set, you send "x UID SEARCH UID y", which will return the message's UID if the message exists and an empty result if not. QRESYNC's `SELECT` arguments provide a natural improvement to this technique.

The problems, of course, are that with a non-QRESYNC server the client will cache messages for longer than necessary, and that depending on how you implement it the client might flicker or have unpleasant delays.

Comment: Alas, this is for offline use, so I can't do this. I have to synchronise the entire database in one go.

Comment: In which case you can store the MSNs as well as UIDs of some or all messages, and then issue "x UID SEARCH 1000,2000,3000,4000,...25000". This will give you 25 UIDs, and by comparing them with the previous MSN/UID maps for those you can know whether each of the 25 sections of the mailbox contain any expunges. If a 1000-message section doesn't contain any, you've found out cheaply, but if one does you'll have to send a more expensive command in order to find out precisely which messages have been expunged. (Note that the arguments to UID SEARCH are MSNs, but the response will contain UIDs.)

Comment: That's really cunning; I can efficiently binary chop through the mailbox comparing the sequence IDs to find the expunged messages. I got as far as planning an implementation before realising that I also need to find messages with changed flags, so I'm going to have to pull down the whole list anyway, so there's no point. But thanks all the same.

Comment: (Put that in your answer and ping me and I'll mark it answered. I'm sure it'll come in useful elsewhere.)

Comment: @DavidGiven okay, done. Yes, flags are impossble. Note that you can sort of handle the \seen flag: 'a UID SEARCH or (uid 1:x-1 unseen) (uid x:* seen)' where x is the previous highest UID in your client cache tends to be fairly small. But overall, this stuff is the raison d'etre for condstore/qresync.